# Можно ли не делать повторный рендер родительского компонента, если нужно повторно рендерить дочерний?

Tags: reactjs, память

```
import React from 'react';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.text}
    <Timer /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Если компонент Timer каждую секунду обновляется, то можно ли лишний раз не обновлять компонент App, если у него не меняются props?

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей ситуации советую изучить memo и useMemo;